# Is it possible to call another Function from a Function called by a PythonVirtualenvOperator?

Tags: python, airflow

I have my example DAG which I am testing on Airflow 1.10.0. When I use the PythonVirtualenvOperator with a python callable as the following example:

```
def  python_virtual_env_callable():
    import requests
    #some code which uses requests library...

....
with dag:
    test_task = PythonVirtualenvOperator(
        task_id='test_task',
        python_callable=python_virtual_env_callable,
        op_kwargs=None,
        requirements=['requests'],
        python_version='3.6',
        system_site_packages=False
     )

    start_task = DummyOperator(task_id='start')
    end_task = DummyOperator(task_id='end')

    start_task >> test_task >> end_task
```

---

the DAG works fine, and I get no errors. The issue arises when I try to call another function from the python_virtual_env_callable function, as shown in the following example:

```
def some_secondary_function():  
    import pandas
    # some code with pandas

def python_virtual_env_callable():
    import requests
    #some code which uses requests library ...
    some_secondary_function() #call to another function
    

....
with dag:
    test_task = PythonVirtualenvOperator(
        task_id='test_task',
        python_callable=python_virtual_env_callable,
        op_kwargs=None,
        requirements=['requests','pandas'],
        python_version='3.6',
        system_site_packages=False
     )

    start_task = DummyOperator(task_id='start')
    end_task = DummyOperator(task_id='end')

    start_task >> test_task >> end_task
```

in this case I get:
"ERROR - Command '['/tmp/venvndxo9eth/bin/python', '/tmp/venvndxo9eth/script.py', '/tmp/venvndxo9eth/script.in', '/tmp/venvndxo9eth/script.out', '/tmp/venvndxo9eth/string_args.txt']' returned non-zero exit status 1."

My question then is:
Is it not possible to call a function from another function called by the PythonVirtualenvOperator?
The same DAG with just the PythonOperator works perfectly fine.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest two options to overcome the issue. The first one is simple - define the method inside of your virtual function callable:

```
def python_virtual_env_callable():
    import requests
    def some_secondary_function():  
        import pandas
        # some code with pandas
    #some code which uses requests library ...
    some_secondary_function() #call to another function
```

The second option is more complex, but makes dags with more code readable. Put a script file "script.py" next to your dag and call it. Here are two functions:

```
@task
def get_script_code():
    with open(os.path.join(get_current_dir(), "script.py")) as f:
        return f.read()

def my_callable(**kwargs):
    import subprocess
    import tempfile
    import json
    with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile("w") as f:
        f.write(kwargs["script"])
        f.flush()
        result = subprocess.run([sys.executable, f.name, json.dumps(kwargs)])
    if result.returncode != 0:
        raise Exception(f"Script returned error code: {result.returncode}")

my_callable_task = PythonVirtualenvOperator(
    task_id="my_callable",
    python_callable=my_callable,
    op_kwargs={
        "script": "{{ ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='get_script_code') }}"
    },
    requirements=[...]
)

get_script_code() >> my_callable_task
```

The get_script_code function is used read the script file and send it to the virtual env using XCOM. The my_callable function is called by the virtual env and runs the script as a subprocess. "sys.exeutable" is used to make sure the requirements installed inside the virtual env can be used. Args are passed to the script and can include dag params / xcom and so on